# Problems with docstring containing backslash characters

Tags: python, doctest

```
import hashlib


def my_function(bytes_):
    """
    >>> my_function(b'\0')
    '6e340b9cffb37a989ca544e6bb780a2c78901d3fb33738768511a30617afa01d'
    """
    return hashlib.sha256(bytes_).hexdigest()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

*Expected behaviour:*  1 test passes

*Actual behaviour:* `ValueError` exception is raised from within `doctest.py`.

```
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I've tried to use `b'\x00'` literal as well with the same result.  How to use null bytes in doctest?  What exactly is the problem here, and is there any fix or not-too-ugly workaround?

Comment: Why would you _want_ a null byte in your documentation? You want your documentation to read `my_function(b'\0')`, not `my_function(b'')`. Am I missing something here? Pretty sure you want to use a raw string there...

Comment: This is an MCVE.  The fact that the code handles null bytes in a particular way *is* actually relevant and necessary in my application.

Comment: Just noticed: [pickle](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/pickletools.py#L252) has doctests that have to address this same double-parse issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your doctest is getting double-parsed. First, Python applies backslash processing to convert `\0` to a null byte in the docstring itself, and then `doctest` tries to run the thing after the `>>>` as Python code and encounters an error because backslash processing has already been applied.

This would also be a problem for anyone just trying to print your docstring, or trying to call `help` on your function.

As with regexes, to avoid the first layer of backslash processing, use raw string notation:

```
def my_function(bytes_):
    r"""
    >>> my_function(b'\0')
    '6e340b9cffb37a989ca544e6bb780a2c78901d3fb33738768511a30617afa01d'
    """
    return hashlib.sha256(bytes_).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want a string to contain a backslash you need to escape it with another backslash. Otherwise, it is trying to escape the following character.

In your case, `b'\0'` will replace `\0` with a null character, hence your error.
Try instead:

```
def my_function(bytes_):
    """
    >>> my_function(b'\\0')
    '6e340b9cffb37a989ca544e6bb780a2c78901d3fb33738768511a30617afa01d'
    """
    return hashlib.sha256(bytes_).hexdigest()
```

Comment: This actually works, but only by a curious accident.  The sha256 of `rb'\0'` is not starting like 6e340b... but like 86f80f...

Comment: i.e. the doctest is now misleading.